# How to find Cartesian equation of parabola with focus at origin and directrix $2x + y = 10$

Tags: calculus, geometry

find a Cartesian equation for the parabola whose
focus is the origin and whose directrix is the line $2x + y = 10$

My attempt :I know  one  formula that  is  If $N$ is a vector normal to $L$ and if $P$ is any point on $L $ the distance $d(X, L)$ from any $X$ to $L$ is given by the formula $d(X, L) =\frac{|(X-P). N}{||N||}\tag 1$

Here $L= \{(x,y) | 2+y =10 \}$

I don't  know  how  to colloborate  this  formula $(1)$  with the  given question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume any point $(x,y)$ on the parabola. Given the focal point $(0,0)$ and the directrix $x+2y=10$, we can establish the equal distance from $(x,y)$ to the focus and the directrix as follows

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{|x+2y-10|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}$$

Simplify to obtain the equation

$$4x^2-4xy+ y^2 +20x+40y-100=0$$